# How to get rid of level 1 and level 2 memory warnings?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm developing an iPhone project,in my application whenever i click on my custom top uinavigationbar right and left button i'm getting level 1 and level 2 memory warnings and my app is getting crash in lower memory devices like iPod touch. I don't Know what is the problem.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without your code, there is now way of telling what exactly is wrong.

Comment: You can get rid of the errors by releasing memory. This is the best we can tell without getting details.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely reason is that you have one or possibly more memory leaks. Use Instruments with the Leaks tool to find them and then fix them.

Another reason is that you're using memory correctly, but simply too much of it. You will then need to find a way to reduce the amount of memory used, for example by storing data you don't need at the moment in files.

Answer (score 1):

[**This**](http://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/finding-xcode-leaks.html) is a good tutorial to let one know about memory leaks and management.

Answer (score 1):

One way to check is Run->Run with performance tool-> Allocations

Here you can find where actually you are getting your memory allocated more.

Accordingly you can manage.

Memory leaks may also may be reason check Memory Leaks too....

Hope it helps......